# Detecting the index in a string that is not printable character with Scala

Tags: string, scala

I have a method that detects the index in a string that is not printable as follows.

```
def isPrintable(v:Char) = v >= 0x20 && v <= 0x7E
val ba = List[Byte](33,33,0,0,0)
ba.zipWithIndex.filter { v => !isPrintable(v._1.toChar) } map {v => v._2}
> res115: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```

The first element of the result list is the index, but I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an `Option[Int]` of the first non-printable character (if one exists), you can do:

```
ba.zipWithIndex.collectFirst{
  case (char, index) if (!isPrintable(char.toChar)) => index
}
> res4: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

If you want all the indices like in your example, just use `collect` instead of `collectFirst` and you'll get back a `List`.

Answer (score 3):

For getting only the first index that meets the given condition:

```
ba.indexWhere(v => !isPrintable(v.toChar))
```

(it returns -1 if nothing is found)

Comment: Does this not returns only one index? Stopping to the first found if I remember correctly.

Comment: I thought OP meant getting the first index?

Comment: I think he wants them all: `> res115: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)`

Comment: He says "the first element of the result list is the index..."

Comment: -1. Why be in such a rush? A single line of code with no context or discussion is almost never a good answer, and this didn't even work as first posted.

Answer (score 0):

**If desired only the first occurrence of non printable char**

Method `span` applied on a `List` delivers two sublists, the first where all the elements hold a condition, the second starts with an element that falsified the condition. In this case consider,

```
val (l,r) = ba.span(b => isPrintable(b.toChar))
l: List(33, 33)
r: List(0, 0, 0)
```

To get the index of the first non printable char,

```
l.size
res: Int = 2
```

---

**If desired all the occurrences of non printable chars**

Consider `partition` of a given `List` for a criteria. For instance, for

```
val ba2 = List[Byte](33,33,0,33,33)  

val (l,r) = ba2.zipWithIndex.partition(b => isPrintable(b._1.toChar))
l: List((33,0), (33,1), (33,3), (33,4))
r: List((0,2))
```

where `r` includes tuples with non printable chars and their position in the original `List`.

Comment: `val ba = List[Byte](33,33,0,33,33)` will fail your tests

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether list of indexes or tuples is needed and I am not sure whether 'ba' needs to be an list of bytes or starts off as a string.

```
 for {  i <- 0 until ba.length if !isPrintable(ba(i).toChar) } yield i
```

here, because people need performance :)

```
 def getNonPrintable(ba:List[Byte]):List[Int] = {
  import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
  var buffer = ListBuffer[Int]()
  @tailrec
  def go(xs: List[Byte],  cur: Int): ListBuffer[Int] = {
    xs match {
      case Nil => buffer
      case y :: ys => {
        if (!isPrintable(y.toChar)) buffer += cur
        go(ys,  cur + 1)
      }
    }
  }
  go(ba, 0)
  buffer.toList
}
```

Comment: ba(i) is expensive for a List (O(i) complexity). you'd have to convert it to Vector first (check "Performance" in the docs here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)

Comment: you are absolutely right, but i wasnt sure whether author actually wanted to use list in the first place. The question was phrased as "detects the index in a string"

Comment: ba is of type List, in any case :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly regexp to found unprintable characters by unicode code points.

Resource: [Regexp page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint)

In such way you can directly filter your string with such pattern, for instance:

```
val text = "this is \n sparta\t\r\n!!!"
text.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1.matches("\\p{C}")).map(_._2)
> res3: Vector(8, 16, 17, 18)
```

As result you'll get Vector with indices of all unprintable characters in String. Check it out